# Having trouble finishing this python code

Tags: python

I need help finishing this code. I cant figure out how to get a total dollar amount. Can anyone help with this? At the end I want it to have a detailed receipt with a total $amount. I can get it to print the receipt but I can figure out how to get a total. I just recently starting writing code so please do not judge me lol.

```
receipt = ""

print("Pizza size choices: ")
print("1 - small ($5)")
print("2 - medium ($7)")
print("3 - large ($10)")
size_choice = int(input("Your choice: "))

while size_choice < 1 or size_choice > 3:
    size_choice = int(input("Not a valid choice: "))

total_cost = 0

if size_choice == 1:
    total_cost += 5
    receipt += "Size: Small ($5)"
elif size_choice == 2:
    total_cost += 7
    receipt += "Size: Medium ($7)"
elif size_choice == 3:
    total_cost += 10
    receipt += "Size: Large ($10)"

receipt += "\n"

print("Pizza crust options: ")
print("1 - thin ($1)")
print("2 - very thin ($1.5)")
print("3 - thick ($2)")
crust_choice = int(input("Your choice: "))

while crust_choice < 1 or crust_choice > 3:
    crust_choice = int(input("Not a valid choice: "))


if crust_choice == 1:
    total_cost += 1
    receipt += "Crust: thin ($1)"
elif crust_choice ==2:
    total_cost += 1.5
    receipt += "Crust: very thin ($1.5)"
elif crust_choice == 3:
    total_cost += 2
    receipt += "Crust: thick ($2)"

receipt += "\n"

print("Pizza sauce options: ")
print("1 - Marinara ($0.50")
print("2 - Ranch ($0.75)")
sauce_choice = int(input("Your choice: "))

while sauce_choice < 1 or sauce_choice > 2:
    sauce_choice = int(input("Not a valid choice: "))


if sauce_choice == 1:
    total_cost += 0.5
    receipt += ("Sauce: Marinara ($0.50)")
elif sauce_choice == 2:
    total_cost += 0.75
    receipt += ("Sauce: Ranch ($0.75)")

receipt += "\n"

print("Cheese options: ")
print("1 - Mozzarella ($0.50")
print("2 - Cheddar ($0.50")
print("3 - Provolone ($0.50)")
cheese_choice = int(input("Your choice: "))

while cheese_choice < 1 or cheese_choice > 3:
    cheese_choice = int(input("Not a valid choice: "))

if cheese_choice == 1:
    total_cost += 0.5
    receipt += ("Cheese: Mozzarella ($0.50)")
elif cheese_choice == 2:
    total_cost += 0.5
    receipt += ("Cheese: Cheddar ($0.50)")
elif cheese_choice ==3:
    total_cost += 0.5
    receipt += ("Cheese: Provolone ($0.50)")

receipt += "\n" 

print("Topping options (Select up to 3): ")
print("1 - Mushrooms")
print("2 - Peppers")
print("3 - Olives")
print("4 - Onions")
print("5 - Pineapple")
print("6 - Spinach")
topping_choice = int(input("Your choice/choices are: "))

while topping_choice < 1 or topping_choice > 6:
    topping_choice = int(input("Not a valid choice: "))

if topping_choice == 1: 
    receipt += ("Mushrooms")
if topping_choice == 2: 
    receipt += ("Peppers")
if topping_choice == 3: 
    receipt += ("Olives")
if topping_choice == 4: 
    receipt += ("Onions")
if topping_choice == 5: 
    receipt += ("Pineapple")
if topping_choice == 6: 
    receipt += ("Spinach")

receipt += "\n"

print(receipt)
```

Comment: Don't you already have a variable for that ```total_cost```?

Comment: You're tracking the cost in the `total_cost` variable, so at the end of the script if you type `print(str(total_cost))` (you have to convert the cost from integer to string in order to print it) then you should see the value that you expect. (Note that toppings appear to be free, and although the prompt says "please select up to three", you don't appear to have the ability to enter more than one.)

Comment: You are correct. Any tips on how to pick 3 toppings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your script because you are already keeping track of the total cost just print the variable `total_cost`.
#Note: This should go at the end of the script

```
print(receipt)
print(f'total cost {total_cost}')
```

**Edit**
Out of the kindness of my heart OP, I have created a basic idea of what you could do to accomplish your goal of giving three topping choices.
The below code asks user for a number of topping choices. Then asks them which toppings they want. It's basic, i'd like you OP to clean it up and put it in the respectable place.

```
chosenToppings = []
while True:
    toppingCount = int(input('How many toppings would you like?: '))
    if toppingCount <= 3:
        for i in range(1,toppingCount+1):
            top = 1
            while top in [1,2,3]:
                top = int(input('Enter choice 1-3: '))
                chosenToppings.append(top)
                break
        break
    else:print('Enter a number less than three please')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question: The user is supposed to be able to pick up to 3 toppings, when I enter 3 numbers in the code it give me an error stating:                  Topping options (Select up to 3):
1 - Mushrooms
2 - Peppers
3 - Olives
4 - Onions
5 - Pineapple
6 - Spinach
Your choice/choices are: 1 2 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\spman\OneDrive\Documents\pizzapt2.py", line 98, in <module>
    topping_choice = int(input("Your choice/choices are: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3'                     How do I fix this?

Comment: Yeah because you cant turn 1 2 3 into an integer. You need to split it at the space, iterate through that list and turn each number to an int.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to print total cost than just print total_cost in last